# d3 charts shows even though data transition is not completed

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

When the data is changed the d3 chart shows all the intermediates stages of the new chart that needs to be shown instead of only show the final chart with the latest data. How to make it only show the final chart without all the intermediate stages

Comment: Disable transitions in your code (must be used in your code with time)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.